# Motor/Generator Set Using Car Alternator

Tags: motor, generator, three-phase

So I've recently been learning that car alternators are just three phase synchronous motors with external DC field excitation. To access the three phases it may be necessary to take them apart, because a lot of them now have internal rectifiers. Here is a good recource: http://www.autoshop101.com/forms/alt_bwoh.pdf

I would like to connect an externally driven alternator to another un-driven alternator and use the first as a generator to make the second rotate. Essentially a small model of how a 3-phase power plant generator can be connected to a 3-phase synchronous motor to make it turn. I was thinking about using a separate DC supply to control the field current of the driven alternator and the un-driven alternator separately.

However, I don't know how to calculate the output voltage of the driven alternator vs RPM and field current. How can I figure this out other than just buying two alternators and trying it? Likewise I don't know how to calculate how fast the second alternator will spin vs. field current and input voltage. For instance if I spin the first alternator at 3600RPM, and apply 5VDC to the field coils of both alternators, will the second alternator actually spin with a light load? Any help finding the relevant equations would be greatly appreciated!

Like I said the end goal is to have a small model of a power plant and show how 3-phase power is generated and can be used to drive a 3-phase motor.

Thanks!

Comment: The alternator will become a current amplified by torque and DC motor driving it or 3 phase inverter driving it from DC. Then the 2nd alternator will become a synchronous motor with RPM controlled by load torque or by a Tach feedback to regulate the prime mover to create a local grid at some new frequency or as a DC-AC-AC VFD grid power system controlled by load current and target RPM.

Comment: Just a warning, car alternators are horribly inefficient, being built down to a price and expected to be fed with spare 'free energy'. But if you're simply building a model to demonstrate principles, that shouldn't matter.

Comment: I am not sure if this is going to work as you expect. Imagine connecting the 3 phase generator to the 3 phase motor as you specify. Also imagine the case where you leave the generator running, and you remove the DC excitation from just the driven supply. Now the back emf in the motor will be zero. The motors coils will be close to a dead short. You would be likely to burn out your motor in this case.

Comment: Good point. However, I know that in a real power grid synchronous machines are used to generate power for other synchronous machines, so there must be a way to do it correctly right?

If I remember correctly you can short the field windings to make it act like an induction motor and get up to synchronous speed, then apply a DC current to lock it in to synchronization.